# How to disable/enable submit button of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple query, I have a big form including a submit button. Now I need to disable the button on page load which I am doing by simple HTML attribute `disabled="true"`. Now I need to enable the button if any of the field failed.

I can achieve this through bind `keypress/keyup` event for all the field and if any one of them has the value update change the attribute for the button.

But somehow I feel its a bad thing for this small achievement. Anyone any suggestion?

I used the following code which work fine:

```
$('#SendForceMessage input[type="text"],#SendForceMessage input[type="file"],#SendForceMessage input[type="number"],#SendForceMessage textarea').on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
    $('.keypress.disabled.redBtn').removeClass('disabled').attr('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: What you're doing sounds like the correct way. Why do you feel it's not right? You could potentially improve it by using the `input` event instead, but it's hard to say if there's any issues in your code without being able to see it

Comment: instead of doing `keyup/keypress` event you should use `blur` event.

Comment: Check pristine, dirty state of form to enable submit button

Comment: You don't need to pass "true" to the disabled attribute of the button, just add "disabled" to the button. How is the validation of the fields done?

Comment: if any of the fields failed? or changed?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't want the way everytime user type something and the function keep hitting, maybe a state change or something simpler function I searching for...

Comment: You should use [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) event. @pixellab

Comment: if it's a small function it's ok if it runs at every value change. 'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.'

Comment: Some code snippet would be very useful in assisting you though....

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal yes I can use blur or onchange functions...but I dont want to keep hitting for everyfeild, just once hit change the state and gone...somthing like this...otherwise I am fine with my current function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the below solution which I used. Below code will enable submit button if there is any value in any field of form. If form get blank after enabling submit button, this will again disable the button.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#main-form").on("keyup", 'input[type="text"]', function () {
            $submitStatus = $("#submitBtnId").prop('disabled');
            if ($(this).val() !== '' && $submitStatus === true) {
                $("#submitBtnId").prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                var textFound = 0;
                $("#main-form").find('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                        textFound = 1;
                    }
                });
                if (textFound == 0) {
                    $("#submitBtnId").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jQuery

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `blur` event with input.Unlike key events `blur` fire only when the focus is removed from the input

```js
function enableButton() {
  //rest of validation here
  console.log('here')
  document.getElementById('submitButton').removeAttribute('disabled', '');

}
```

```html
<form>


  <input type="text" onblur='enableButton()'>
  <input type="text" onblur='enableButton()'>
  <input type="text" onblur='enableButton()'>
  <input type="text" onblur='enableButton()'>

  <button id='submitButton' type='submit' disabled='disabled'>Submit</button>

</form>
```